# Embedding a chart from Excel in a specified placeholder in Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to copy a chart from an Excel spreadsheet into a Powerpoint presentation. I already have a separate routine that opens PPT and navigates to the relevant slide.

On the slide (2), I have a placeholder (shape 3), where I want to embed my chart, preserving the link to Excel.

When I run the code, I get an error: "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" on the last line of execution.

The code looks is as follows:

```
Sub MoveExcelObjectsToPresentation()

Set PPTapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set PPTpres = PPTapp.ActivePresentation

Dim waterfallChart As Chart

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 8").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

PPTpres.Slides(2).Shapes(3).PasteSpecial '(DataType:=ppPasteOLEObject, Link:=msoTrue)


End Sub
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Use www.pptxbuilder.com, it does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the issue with last line of code was, but the code works correctly if I replace the last line with the following:

```
With PPTpres
    .Slides(2).Shapes(8).Select
    .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetaFile)
End With
```